# How to group-by results of survey in mongodb and mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an action collection in my app, which have the following objects structure:

```
    {
        "type" : "evMove",
        "userId" : "55fbbb2a34d594085988aa70",
        "data" : {
            "evId"   : "55fdaa53cca301f758f4023d",
            "moveId" : "55fdaa53cca301f758f4023f"
        }
    },
    {
        "type" : "game",
        "userId" : "55fgdfa34d594085988aa70",
        "data" : {
            ...
        }
    },
    {
        "type" : "evMove",
        "userId" : "55fbbb2aasd34d595988aa60",
        "data" : {
            "evId"   : "55fdaa53cca301f758f4023d",
            "moveId" : "55fdaa53cca301f758f4023f"
        }
    },
{
        "type" : "evMove",
        "userId" : "55fbbb2a34d594085988aa30",
        "data" : {
            "evId"   : "55fdaa53cca301f758f4023d",
            "moveId" : "55fdaa53cca301f758f4023g"
        }
    }
```

I need to return a result in mongodb and mongoose that return the following:

```
 for event id: 55fdaa53cca301f758f4023d

  moveId:55fdaa53cca301f758f4023d, count:2
  moveId:55fdaa53cca301f758f4023g, count:1
```

Which means the following if i do it in javascript and with no group by like query:

```
db.actions.find({'type':'evMove','data.evId':'55fdaa53cca301f758f4023d'})

 resultArray = {
       55fdaa53cca301f758f4023d : 0,
       55fdaa53cca301f758f4023g : 0
    };
    results.forEach(function(res){
         resultArray[res.data.evMove]++;
    );
```

How can i do the group by that will give me more or less the results i want (the move and the count of it) in mongodb and mongoose?

Comment: So what do you want? Is it the a count of distinct `moveId` values for each distinct `evId` value?

Comment: yes! right on what you said, it will be more specific in my query, meaning, only for one evId, not for all my actions table evIds...

Comment: i have one evId and for it i have let's say 4 options for the user to choose (the moveId), i just want to count how much users chose one move instead of the other, only for one evId at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) which can "group" on the specified keys. At first you group on both, and though not exactly in the format you asked, the second [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) "rolls up" the results into an array:

```js
Model.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "type": "evMove",
        "data.evId": new ObjectId("55fdaa53cca301f758f4023d")
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "evId": "$data.evId",
            "moveId": "$data.moveId"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.evId",
        "moves": {
            "$push": { 
                "moveId": "$_id.moveId",
                "count": "$count"
            }
        }
    }}
],function(err,results) {
    // results in here
});
```

Which gives you a result like this:

```js
{ 
    "_id": "55fdaa53cca301f758f4023d",
    "moves": [
        { "moveId": "55fdaa53cca301f758f4023d", "count": 2 }
        { "moveId": "55fdaa53cca301f758f4023g", "count": 1 }
    ]
```

}

Also note that if you want this for "multiple" `eventId` values, then just remove that line from the [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/).

And of course since the aggregation pipeline does not perform the "autocasting" that mongoose does in other `.find()` type operations ( based on schema ) then you need to "cast" the types yourself. Hence the `ObjectId` method from the core driver. But that is only required where you need to `$match` the content to such an `_id` value, as all other evaluation is internal to the pipeline itself.